# Jwt type won't load alongside integrated twilio

Tags: api, jwt, owin, katana, owin-middleware

I have integrated twilio and it has updated packages of jwt and now i am
getting error for this UseJwtBearerAuthentication() method. How 
can i resolved this error as i cannot downgrade my packages since it has a
dependency for twilio?

```
 private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app) {
    var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AngularHostURL"];
    string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
    byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new 
                    IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, 
                    audienceSecret)
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

The exception  i am getting is:

```
Could not load type Could not load 
'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.1.2.0, 
Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

Comment: hello i resolved this by updating my microsoft.owin.security to latest 4.0.0 and updated my code  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                    IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = new IIssuerSecurityKeyProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                    }
                });